# Excel not reading time as time

Tags: excel, time, formatting, formula

I have this data that excel is not recognizing at hh:mm.  I have changed formatting, removed any unnecessary spaces and it will not recognize.  Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: TIMEVALUE function maybe?

Comment: or multiply the cell by `1`.

Comment: That worked - thank you!